# How to refresh checking if function has been called in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering is it possible to refresh checking if certain function has been called without re-runing the program.

Example:

```
def check():
      check.has_been_called = True
      pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
      check.has_been_called = False
```

When I do this a while loop is stoped from working in my program. But when I want to make loop to start working again I need to re-run my program to refresh if function to stop the loop has been called or not.

So is it possible to make that function which stops the while loop refreshes itself everytime after it's been called.

To be clear completly I want that after function has been called it refreshes to as not been called.

Hope yall can understand this.

Comment: What does this loop you want to "start working again" look like?

Comment: Why don't you just say `check.has_been_called = False` at the point in your program where you want to set it to false?

Comment: Neither of two solutions above didn't helped. My loop looks like this - while True: do this and that if check.has_been_called: break     else: pass

Comment: The `break` keyword is used to end (jump out of) the loop. It doesn't just pause the loop. To start it again, you need to loop the loop :) Also set `check.has_been_called = False` in the outer loop.